# Solar Battery Bank 12v/24v Parallel (12)

Tags: batteries, solar-cell

I have twelve 12 V/200 Ah Lithium Ion batteries I want to run in parallel.
Everything I read and recommendations say run no more than 4 batteries in parallel. I have 12 I want to hook up to my solar. I'm not sure exactly how to do it.

I totally understand the concept of running the batteries in parallel. So I would need to run 3 strings of 4 batteries? If that's the case would I need a buss bar to tie the wiring back to the inverter? All the wiring diagrams I found are simple all 12 batteries wired in parallel together.

Comment: You can parallel as many as you want in parallel if you follow the regular precautions. Individual fuses spring to mind too.

Comment: Are you saying run them in 2 strings which is what I had initially planned and add individual fuses to each battery? I Nowhere have I found information on fusing individual batteries. How to program the 40 amp charge controllers(2) when the battery manufactures only provided programing for 4 batteries.